# Windows. Python 3+. Исключительная блокировка файла

Tags: python-3.x, windows, файловая-система

Не создается блокировка файла при работе через python.

```
# пример
with open(filePath, mode="wb+") as f:
  print(filePath)
  input("Любой ввод для завершения")
  ...
```

Т.е. в момент выполнения скрипта я могу открыть файл в любой программе, отредактировать и сохранить.
Как заблокировать возможность чтения/записи для других приложений?

Comment: "открыть файл в любой программе, отредактировать и сохранить." Поставить файлу атрибут "только для чтения"

Comment: И дергать атрибуты каждый раз как мне самому нужно будет что-то записать?

Comment: А у вас есть другие идеи?

Comment: Я уточняю)  У меня нет. Только вопрос: почему это не реализовано по-умолчанию?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать библиотеку [filelock](https://py-filelock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from filelock import Timeout, FileLock

lock = FileLock("high_ground.txt.lock")
with lock:
    with open("high_ground.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write("You were the chosen one.")
```

Обратите внимание на комментарий:

***Не используйте** FileLock для блокировки файла, в который вы хотите выполнить запись, вместо этого создайте отдельный .lock файл, как показано выше.*

Comment: В процессе поисков натыкался на данную библиотеку. К сожалению она не выполняет то, что мне нужно.